# Android software for the system administrator on the move

Tags: mobile-devices, android

My company has over service through Verizon, and AT&T Service in the area is "shoddy" at its best, so I haven't been able to join the "iPhone party" like so many of my fellow system administrators have been able to.

That being said, this week finally a phone I like has hit Verizon, the [HTC Incredible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_Incredible). (I've been waiting for the Desire or Nexus One, but after seeing spec sheets and reviews, HTC Incredible comes out ahead anyway).

So (finally) I'm looking for Android Apps that are "gotta-haves" for system administrators.

I've found the bottom three. If there are others you prefer over these let me know.

RDP Program - [RemoteRDP](http://www.toremote.com/)

SSH Client - [ConnectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/)

Nagios - [NagMonDroid](http://community.nagios.org/2009/11/11/nagmondroid-an-android-nagios-interface/)

Reply with your favorite Android App and why!

Comment: This type of question should be a wiki.

Comment: I find Nagroid to be a superior nagios client to NagMonDroid.

Comment: This type of question belongs on superuser- unless they start putting server OSes on phones...

Comment: @Jim, if the device is used as a sysadmin tool I blieve it's a perfectly valid question for this site. SU is not a suitable site to ask questions about sysadmin tools. However, it's very subjective at best which is why it should be a wiki.

Comment: CIDR Calculator

Comment: MAC Address Search

Comment: Converted to Community Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Wi-Fi analyzer for debugging Wi-Fi coverage
- proxoid to tether the phone to something of the more useful size

Non system administration specific but generally useful:

- k-9 Mail
- Dolphin Browser
- OI notepad + OI Safe to keep encrypted notes
- BeamReader to read PDF files

Comment: wifi analyzer was a very nice upgrade to the one I was using, I'll have to try proxoid, to see if it beats easytether

Answer (score 2):

This is my list of must have android apps for sysadmins:

- connectbot SSH client
- beem XMPP (Jabber) client
- PocketCloud RDP/VNC Client
- Linux & Unix Commands
- Zabbix on the go (Client for Zabbix Monitoring Solution)
- nagroid (Nagios Client)
- FBReaderJ (e-book reader)
- Net Tools (handle ping, check port 80, dns / IP lookup, HTTP header download, netstat)

Answer (score 2):

This is my list: 
    connectbot SSH client
    beem XMPP (Jabber) client
    PocketCloud RDP/VNC Client
    Linux & Unix Commands
    Zabbix on the go (Client for Zabbix Monitoring Solution)
    nagroid (Nagios Client)
    FBReaderJ (e-book reader)
    Net Tools (handle ping, check port 80, dns / IP lookup, HTTP header download, netstat)

Answer (score 1):

Kindle, droid style.  Especially once they add searching...

Comment: Yes! I downloaded this the day it was available.  I love it.

Answer (score 1):

I find KeePassDroid very helpful since it works with KeePassX datafiles so I can keep password safe and secure and access them wherever I need.

http://www.keepassdroid.com/

Answer (score 0):

I like the [iTap mobile RDP](http://itap-mobile.com/android/rdp) client. It supports all security features of RDP including TS-Gateway.